# STM32 Keil - Can not access target

Tags: stm32, sensors, target, keil, stm32f4discovery

I'm trying to debug my stm32f407 project in Keil but I get the message "cannot access target shutting down debug session ". I'm trying to work with the DHT11 sensor and I want to show the result on the LCD. but I can't debug the code and can't figure out what is the problem.
for the dht11 sensor, I used the guidness in
https://controllerstech.com/using-dht11-sensor-with-stm32/
I can program the MCU and run the code, the problem is only in debugging.

```
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "adc.h"
#include "i2c.h"
#include "tim.h"
#include "usart.h"
#include "gpio.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

#include "tm_stm32_hd44780.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
  
#include "bh1750.h"
#include "DHT.h"
/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
char DM[35]="temp is: ";
char RT[35]="humidity is: ";
char ch[10]="10";
uint8_t TEMP;
uint8_t RH;

//strncat(tara, &ch, 1);

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */
#define DHT_H_11
DHT_DataTypedef DHT11_Data;
float Temperature, Humidity;

#define DHT11_PORT GPIOA
#define DHT11_PIN GPIO_PIN_1

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();
  MX_I2C1_Init();
  MX_I2C2_Init();
  MX_TIM6_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  MX_USART3_UART_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
    TM_HD44780_Init(16,2);
  TM_HD44780_Puts(0,0,(char*)DM);
    TM_HD44780_Puts(10,10,(char*)TEMP);
  
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
    while (1)
    {
        
        
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

     /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
 
    
        DHT_GetData(&DHT11_Data);
    
    Temperature = DHT11_Data.Temperature;
      Humidity = DHT11_Data.Humidity;
      HAL_Delay(3000);
    }
     
        Temperature=(char) TEMP;
      Humidity= (char) RH;
      HAL_Delay(1000);
      TM_HD44780_Puts(10,10,(char*)TEMP);
      TM_HD44780_Puts(0,0,"STM32 <3");
    /* USER CODE END 3 */
    }
```

Comment: Please, give some more information. If you start a new empty project, can you upload and debug it?

Comment: I used the updated code in https://controllerstech.com/using-dht11-sensor-with-stm32/ and I tried to show the result on LCD. but nothing is being shown after starting the sensor commands. I can run the code but I can't debug it./while (1)
  {
  
  
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  DHT_GetData(&DHT11_Data);
   Temperature = DHT11_Data.Temperature;
   Humidity = DHT11_Data.Humidity;
   HAL_Delay(3000);
 }
 Temperature=(char) TEMP;
   Humidity= (char) RH;
   HAL_Delay(1000);
   TM_HD44780_Puts(10,10,(char*)TEMP);
   TM_HD44780_Puts(0,0,"STM32 <3");

Comment: You need to include all this helpful info into the question, properly formatted, please

Comment: sorry, I'm a little new to this. I've added the code here.The added link is also helpful

Comment: Also add that you can program the MCU and run the code, the problem is only in debugging. Overall, the more info you give, the better. Better too much info than too little. The problem seems to be in the debug configuration. Maybe preprocessor definitions. Never worked with keil, can't help much specifically there.